# Using Cmake, how do I prevent library sources from being included in my IDE?

Tags: c++, xcode, compilation, cmake

Using a bunch of different libraries in my project (from GitHub sources, not precompiled), I add them to my target like this in my root `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
add_subdirectory(lib/glew-1.13.0/build/cmake)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/glew-1.13.0/include/)

...

target_link_libraries(MyApp glew ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} ... )
```

However, you can see from the screenshot below that Xcode includes all of the sources for those libraries in my project, which makes an insanely long list that I have to scroll through to find *my* code.

I have tried the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` flag in the `add_subdirectory` command, which removes the library sources from my Xcode project, but then I cannot compile my project because Xcode doesn't compile the library at all.

Additionally, Xcode gives me tons of warnings from the libraries that I don't really care about. Using the `SYSTEM` flag with the `include_directories` command doesn't fix it.

What's the best way to solve this? Should I be compiling my libraries as a completely separate part of my build process rather than compiling them with my executable?

[image: Xcode Sources]

Comment: Use externalproject_add to build the external projects. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/ExternalProject.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being unfamiliar with C++, I thought that all of my libraries should be compiled along with my project every time. I ended up solving this by writing a shell script that precompiles all of my libraries once as static libraries, and now I don't have to worry about their sources in my IDE, plus I get faster compile times.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it will work, but try this:

turn on the `USE_FOLDERS` in your root CMakeLists.txt

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
```

And then after you've added all the projects, set the FOLDER target property on all of the third party libraries:

```
set_property(TARGET target1 target2 ...
             PROPERTY FOLDER "ThirdPartyLibs")
```